# Diagnose Meteor (Node.js) service hangs

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js, meteor

I have a Meteor (Node.js) app in production that keeps hanging unexplainably in production. I have put a number of log statements in the code, so I can see that it hangs on a certain method.

My question is if there are any other tools other that the console log that might give me insight into the resource consumption of a Node.js app. Something that might tell me why the app is hanging.

The method on which the server hangs is a method that uses a geocluster and geolib NPM. It usually happens after a method where the Facebook-node-SDK is called.

I am thinking that there might be memory consumption from the calls to the geo npm, or open http connections from the facebook-node-sdk?

Please let me know if there is more information that I can provide. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could try `node-inspector` and pass environment run vars to meteor via `NODE_OPTIONS='--debug-brk' meteor run` and try your luck there.

(2017 update: there was an answer here referencing Kadira (kadira.io) however this service is no more.. sad).

You may also try the built-in NodeJS devtools available since 6.3. If you read the node-inspector github repo, you can see a blog post referenced there to get started:

https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27#.pmqejrn8q

Comment: Hey thanks for mentioning Kadira. Shall we discuss about the error tracking issue offline: http://support.kadira.io/
happy to fix it.

Comment: See? this is why I love Kadira. Certainly, @ArunodaSusiripala :)

Comment: Thanks for the all star answers and advice. I have Kadira installed and will continue to try and chase this down. Here is a related question on mup I am throwing out there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821631/how-does-meteor-mup-use-forever @ArunodaSusiripala :)

Comment: As of May 2017 Kadira is no more. `As of today, May 15th, 2017, we are officially shutting down kadira.io service.`

Comment: @RobertH yeah that's a bummer. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try Webstorm, version 9 has meteor support, [debugging included](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/09/meteor-support-in-webstorm-9/).

Comment: Man, I wish it were that easy...I am having a tough time reproducing it in my dev environment. It exhibits in production 1-2 times per day. But Webstorm 9 is pretty sweet though right? :)