# How does Meteor mup use forever?

Tags: node.js, meteor, forever

I can read in the Meteor mup documentation that it uses forever to restart a process if it crashes:

https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up

At the command line if I issue a "forever list" it reports

```
info:    No forever processes running
```

I have a Meteor app that keeps hanging and was wondering if I was using mup correctly, or if Forever would help.

Any advice would be appreciated. Please let me know if there is more information that I can provide.

- Also someone with a higher reputation please tag this question with "mup" if that's possible.

Answer (score 3):

Forever should list the process if it's running.

Check logs of that server with: `tail -f /var/log/upstart/meteor.log`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at my question :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to see the forever processes by adding the -H flag to sudo. sudo by itself was not revealing the processes.

```
ubuntu@ip-123-45-67-890:~$ sudo -H forever list
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command  script      forever pid   logfile                 uptime         
data:    [0] Jaj_ userdown app/main.js 13041   13047 /root/.forever/Jaj_.log 0:16:56:27.894
```

Looks like forever stores process information in the user's home directory, and somewhere in the mup process it was elevated to root and used that home directory. -H evidently made it look there.